# PDO bind paramaters with an array

Tags: pdo, dynamic

I am trying to create a method in PHP, that will dynamically bind parameters to a PDO query statement. Unfortunately, in my code below, i can only bind 1 parameter, because adding more parameters will override the previous parameters. Nevertheless, is there a good way to fix this problem?

I hope someone can help. Thanks!

```
function executeQuery($query, $critArr = null) {
    $rows = array();
        try {
            $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($query);
            if (!empty($critArr)) {
                foreach($critArr as $cKey=>$cValue) {
                    $stmt->bindParam($cKey, $cValue);  //!!
                }
            }
            $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.  The [`execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method *already takes* an array of parameters:

```
function executeQuery($query, $critArr = null) {
    $rows = array();
        try {
            $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($critArr);
            // ...
```

The original problem is that [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) works by reference, and `foreach` simply reuses the same variables over and over rather than destroy them at the bottom of the loop and (re)create them at the top.  You were effectively re-binding the same variable over and over.  (Incidentally, this is the same problem that the `mysqli` extension has, while it also lacks the convenient already-takes-an-array `execute` method.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function improved with passing foreach $cValue by reference &$cValue. This should solve your problem.

```
function executeQuery($query, $critArr = null) {

    $rows = array();
        try {
            $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($query);
            if (!empty($critArr)) {
                foreach($critArr as $cKey=>&$cValue) {
                    $stmt->bindParam($cKey, $cValue);  //!!
                }
            }
            $stmt->execute();
```